# ANDROID : Changing Text Colour on pressing Button in Edit Text

Tags: android

I have 2 things:

`EditText` and One `Button` .

I write something in `EditText` and then Press `Button` . In an ON click Listener of that `Button` 
I set the text color of `EditText` to "Red".

Problem is that the text which was written before clicking `Button` also changes to red whereas I want only the characters to become red which are now typed by the user in the EditText.

Could anyone please help me ???

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext) in the Android FAQ might help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code

```
EditText __text__ = new EditText(this);
__text__.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
```